# How to make docker container to use host network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running docker for mac. My docker compose configuration file is:

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  base:
    build:
      context: .

  dev:
    network_mode: "host"
    extends:
      service: base
```

when the container is launched via `docker-compose run --rm dev sh`, it can't ping a IP address (172.25.36.32). But I can ping this address from host. I have set `network_mode: "host"` on the configuration file. How can I make the docker container share host network?

I found that `host` network doesn't work for Mac. Is there a solution for that in Mac?

Below is the `docker network inspect ID` output:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "my_container_default",
        "Id": "0441cf2b99b692d2047ded88d29a470e2622a1669a7bfce96804b50d609dc3b0",
        "Created": "2019-08-27T06:06:30.984427063Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "22d3e7500ccfdc7fcd192a9f5977ef32e086e340908b1c0ff007e4144cc91f2e": {
                "Name": "time-series-api_dev_run_b35174fdf692",
                "EndpointID": "23924b4f68570bc99e01768db53a083533092208a3c8c92b20152c7d2fefe8ce",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "time-series-api",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.1"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start the `container` with `up` option not `run` since run override many options:

```
docker-compose up dev
```

or you may try with `--use-aliases` with `run`

> --use-aliases         Use the service's network aliases in the network(s) the
>                             container connects to.

see [this](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/6403)

**P.S** 
After your update

the following will work on `MAC`

```
dev:

  network: host
  extends:
    service: base
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to add `network` option during the `build`. Try with

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  base:
    build:
      context: .
      network: host
  dev:
    network_mode: "host"
    extends:
      service: base
```

**EDIT**: Works on Linux, please see documentation for [Mac](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

*The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.*

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't seem to work. The host doesn't work on Mac.

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't work for mac. I wonder is there any solution for Mac to get around this?

Comment: I can't ping the IP address from docker container.

Comment: even with ```bridge``` you are unable to ping ? check this issue https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2345